# ESP8266 as NTP Server?

Tags: server, local, esp8266, ntp

I have ESP8266 with RTC-DS3231 stored Time on it
how I can set ESP8266 NTP Server to provide time to other local devices
I search and I found NTP server with GPS
I need only casting time from RTC to UDP NTP
even if not accurate is that possible?

[I used processNTP from here](https://github.com/Montecri/GPSTimeServer)

here is my code (plz tell me if there is wrong):

```
//Libraries ESP-12E Module
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>

#include <time.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

time_t now;
RTC_DS3231 rtc;

// Needed for UDP functionality
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
// Time Server Port
#define NTP_PORT 123
static const int NTP_PACKET_SIZE = 48;
// buffers for receiving and sending data
byte packetBuffer[NTP_PACKET_SIZE];
// An Ethernet UDP instance
WiFiUDP Udp;
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL; // to convert unix time to epoch

const char* ssid     = "router_ssid";
const char* password = "router_password";
const char* WiFi_hostname = "ESP8266";

String toStringAddZero(int data)
{
  String st = "";
  if (data < 10)
  {
    st = "0" + String(data);
  }
  else
  {
    st = String(data);
  }
  return st;
}

String syncNTP(bool adjust = false) {
  int se, mi, ho, ye, mo, da;
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  time(&now);
  timeinfo = localtime(&now);

  se = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_sec).toInt();
  mi = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_min).toInt();
  ho = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_hour).toInt();
  ye = (timeinfo->tm_year) + 1900;
  mo = toStringAddZero((timeinfo->tm_mon) + 1).toInt();
  da = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_mday).toInt();
  
  if (adjust) {
    if (String(ye) != "1970") {
      rtc.adjust(DateTime( ye , mo , da , ho , mi , se ));
    }
  }

  char dateBuffer[80];
  sprintf(dateBuffer, "%02u%02u%02u%02u%02u.%02u", mo, da , ho, mi, ye, se);
  return (dateBuffer);
}

void ntp() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", String(syncNTP()));
}

void ntp_adjust() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", String(syncNTP(true)));
}

void processNTP()
{

  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize)
  {
    //time(&now); //if not RTC used
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
    IPAddress Remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    int PortNum = Udp.remotePort();

#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Received UDP packet size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      Serial.print(Remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3)
      {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.print(PortNum);

    byte LIVNMODE = packetBuffer[0];
    Serial.print("  LI, Vers, Mode :");
    Serial.print(packetBuffer[0], HEX);

    byte STRATUM = packetBuffer[1];
    Serial.print("  Stratum :");
    Serial.print(packetBuffer[1], HEX);

    byte POLLING = packetBuffer[2];
    Serial.print("  Polling :");
    Serial.print(packetBuffer[2], HEX);

    byte PRECISION = packetBuffer[3];
    Serial.print("  Precision :");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer[3], HEX);

    for (int z = 0; z < NTP_PACKET_SIZE; z++)
    {
      Serial.print(packetBuffer[z], HEX);
      if (((z + 1) % 4) == 0)
      {
        Serial.println();
      }
    }
    Serial.println();

#endif

    packetBuffer[0] = 0b00100100; // LI, Version, Mode
    //packetBuffer[1] = 1 ;   // stratum
    //think that should be at least 4 or so as you do not use fractional seconds

    packetBuffer[1] = 4;    // stratum
    packetBuffer[2] = 6;    // polling minimum
    packetBuffer[3] = 0xFA; // precision

    packetBuffer[7] = 0; // root delay
    packetBuffer[8] = 0;
    packetBuffer[9] = 8;
    packetBuffer[10] = 0;

    packetBuffer[11] = 0; // root dispersion
    packetBuffer[12] = 0;
    packetBuffer[13] = 0xC;
    packetBuffer[14] = 0;

    //int year;
    //byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
    unsigned long date, time, age;
    uint32_t timestamp, tempval;
    //time_t t = now; //if not RTC used
    time_t t = rtc.now().unixtime() - 10800;// Ajust for your location GMT(+3 * 3600) = 10800

    //gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
    //timestamp = numberOfSecondsSince1900Epoch(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);

    //timestamp = numberOfSecondsSince1900Epoch(year(t), month(t), day(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t));
    // Better, less verbose, more elegant timestamp calculation, suggested by cheise @ Github - 20230206
    timestamp = t + seventyYears;

#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println(timestamp);
    //print_date(gps);
#endif

    tempval = timestamp;

    packetBuffer[12] = 71; //"G";
    packetBuffer[13] = 80; //"P";
    packetBuffer[14] = 83; //"S";
    packetBuffer[15] = 0;  //"0";

    // reference timestamp
    packetBuffer[16] = (tempval >> 24) & 0XFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[17] = (tempval >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[18] = (tempval >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[19] = (tempval)&0xFF;

    packetBuffer[20] = 0;
    packetBuffer[21] = 0;
    packetBuffer[22] = 0;
    packetBuffer[23] = 0;

    //copy originate timestamp from incoming UDP transmit timestamp
    packetBuffer[24] = packetBuffer[40];
    packetBuffer[25] = packetBuffer[41];
    packetBuffer[26] = packetBuffer[42];
    packetBuffer[27] = packetBuffer[43];
    packetBuffer[28] = packetBuffer[44];
    packetBuffer[29] = packetBuffer[45];
    packetBuffer[30] = packetBuffer[46];
    packetBuffer[31] = packetBuffer[47];

    //receive timestamp
    packetBuffer[32] = (tempval >> 24) & 0XFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[33] = (tempval >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[34] = (tempval >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[35] = (tempval)&0xFF;

    packetBuffer[36] = 0;
    packetBuffer[37] = 0;
    packetBuffer[38] = 0;
    packetBuffer[39] = 0;

    //transmitt timestamp
    packetBuffer[40] = (tempval >> 24) & 0XFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[41] = (tempval >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[42] = (tempval >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[43] = (tempval)&0xFF;

    packetBuffer[44] = 0;
    packetBuffer[45] = 0;
    packetBuffer[46] = 0;
    packetBuffer[47] = 0;

    // Reply to the IP address and port that sent the NTP request

    Udp.beginPacket(Remote, PortNum);
    Udp.write(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
}

void init_wifi() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.hostname(WiFi_hostname);
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(30);       // how long to try to connect for before continuing
  wifiManager.setConfigPortalTimeout(180); // auto close configportal after n seconds
  if (!wifiManager.autoConnect(WiFi_hostname, "password")) {
    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
  }
  //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
  Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");
}

void setup() {
  init_wifi();
  //configTime(int timezone, int daylightOffset_sec, const char* server1, const char* server2, const char* server3)
  configTime(10800, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "asia.pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov"); // Ajust for your location GMT(+3 * 3600) = 10800
  now = time(nullptr);
  delay(2000);

  server.on ( "/ntp", ntp );
  server.on ( "/ntp_adjust", ntp_adjust );

  ArduinoOTA.begin();
  server.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  // Startup UDP
  Udp.begin(NTP_PORT);
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
  server.handleClient();
  processNTP();
}
```

Respond:

[image]

Comment: This sounds a bit like the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Are you sure you want or need to create an NTP server? Can you explain the problem that you are trying to solve by using an ESP8266 as an NTP Server?

Comment: And why would you want a not accurate NTP server? What's the point?

Comment: my internet is not stable and I have many devices need pool Time from NTP for set time (Tv Box, Android DVB ....) , I wonder if I can make ESP NTP Server time so I can set NTP server is My ESP Address

Comment: sorry my English is not the best
here is some one ask the Question better than me https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/imby01/help_local_ntp_server/
I will Edit my Question with more information

Comment: If I sum up, you want to integrate an NTP server in your code. That's right ?

Comment: @tuyau2poil yes, what I miss now is read RTC and send with processNTP

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working but nothing important. missing some declaration as :

```
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
time_t now;
```

I test it without RTC and it works now fine. as I have no RTC to test, you may test yourself and comme back if some others questions.

working sketch :

```
//Libraries ESP-12E Module
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>

#include <time.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

#define DEBUG 1

RTC_DS3231 rtc;

// Needed for UDP functionality
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
// Time Server Port
#define NTP_PORT 123
static const int NTP_PACKET_SIZE = 48;
// buffers for receiving and sending data
byte packetBuffer[NTP_PACKET_SIZE];
// An Ethernet UDP instance
WiFiUDP Udp;
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const unsigned long seventyYears = 2208988800UL; // to convert unix time to epoch
time_t now;
const char* ssid     = "SSID";
const char* password = "password";
const char* WiFi_hostname = "ESP8266";

String toStringAddZero(int data)
{
  String st = "";
  if (data < 10)
  {
    st = "0" + String(data);
  }
  else
  {
    st = String(data);
  }
  return st;
}

String syncNTP(bool adjust = false) {
  int se, mi, ho, ye, mo, da;
  struct tm *timeinfo;
  time(&now);
  timeinfo = localtime(&now);

  se = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_sec).toInt();
  mi = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_min).toInt();
  ho = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_hour).toInt();
  ye = (timeinfo->tm_year) + 1900;
  mo = toStringAddZero((timeinfo->tm_mon) + 1).toInt();
  da = toStringAddZero(timeinfo->tm_mday).toInt();

  if (adjust) {
    if (String(ye) != "1970") {
      rtc.adjust(DateTime( ye , mo , da , ho , mi , se ));
    }
  }

  char dateBuffer[80];
  sprintf(dateBuffer, "%02u%02u%02u%02u%02u.%02u", mo, da , ho, mi, ye, se);
  return (dateBuffer);
}

void ntp() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", String(syncNTP()));
}

void ntp_adjust() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", String(syncNTP(true)));
}

void processNTP()
{

  // if there's data available, read a packet
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize)
  {
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
    IPAddress Remote = Udp.remoteIP();
    int PortNum = Udp.remotePort();

#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Received UDP packet size ");
    Serial.println(packetSize);
    Serial.print("From ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      Serial.print(Remote[i], DEC);
      if (i < 3)
      {
        Serial.print(".");
      }
    }
    Serial.print(", port ");
    Serial.print(PortNum);

    byte LIVNMODE = packetBuffer[0];
    Serial.print("  LI, Vers, Mode :");
    Serial.print(packetBuffer[0], HEX);

    byte STRATUM = packetBuffer[1];
    Serial.print("  Stratum :");
    Serial.print(packetBuffer[1], HEX);

    byte POLLING = packetBuffer[2];
    Serial.print("  Polling :");
    Serial.print(packetBuffer[2], HEX);

    byte PRECISION = packetBuffer[3];
    Serial.print("  Precision :");
    Serial.println(packetBuffer[3], HEX);

    for (int z = 0; z < NTP_PACKET_SIZE; z++)
    {
      Serial.print(packetBuffer[z], HEX);
      if (((z + 1) % 4) == 0)
      {
        Serial.println();
      }
    }
    Serial.println();

#endif

    packetBuffer[0] = 0b00100100; // LI, Version, Mode
    //packetBuffer[1] = 1 ;   // stratum
    //think that should be at least 4 or so as you do not use fractional seconds

    packetBuffer[1] = 4;    // stratum
    packetBuffer[2] = 6;    // polling minimum
    packetBuffer[3] = 0xFA; // precision

    packetBuffer[7] = 0; // root delay
    packetBuffer[8] = 0;
    packetBuffer[9] = 8;
    packetBuffer[10] = 0;

    packetBuffer[11] = 0; // root dispersion
    packetBuffer[12] = 0;
    packetBuffer[13] = 0xC;
    packetBuffer[14] = 0;

    //int year;
    //byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
    unsigned long date, time, age;
    uint32_t timestamp, tempval;
    time_t t = now;

    //gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
    //timestamp = numberOfSecondsSince1900Epoch(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);

    //timestamp = numberOfSecondsSince1900Epoch(year(t), month(t), day(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t));
    // Better, less verbose, more elegant timestamp calculation, suggested by cheise @ Github - 20230206
    timestamp = t + seventyYears;

#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println(timestamp);
    //print_date(gps);
#endif

    tempval = timestamp;

    packetBuffer[12] = 71; //"G";
    packetBuffer[13] = 80; //"P";
    packetBuffer[14] = 83; //"S";
    packetBuffer[15] = 0;  //"0";

    // reference timestamp
    packetBuffer[16] = (tempval >> 24) & 0XFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[17] = (tempval >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[18] = (tempval >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[19] = (tempval) & 0xFF;

    packetBuffer[20] = 0;
    packetBuffer[21] = 0;
    packetBuffer[22] = 0;
    packetBuffer[23] = 0;

    //copy originate timestamp from incoming UDP transmit timestamp
    packetBuffer[24] = packetBuffer[40];
    packetBuffer[25] = packetBuffer[41];
    packetBuffer[26] = packetBuffer[42];
    packetBuffer[27] = packetBuffer[43];
    packetBuffer[28] = packetBuffer[44];
    packetBuffer[29] = packetBuffer[45];
    packetBuffer[30] = packetBuffer[46];
    packetBuffer[31] = packetBuffer[47];

    //receive timestamp
    packetBuffer[32] = (tempval >> 24) & 0XFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[33] = (tempval >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[34] = (tempval >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[35] = (tempval) & 0xFF;

    packetBuffer[36] = 0;
    packetBuffer[37] = 0;
    packetBuffer[38] = 0;
    packetBuffer[39] = 0;

    //transmitt timestamp
    packetBuffer[40] = (tempval >> 24) & 0XFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[41] = (tempval >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[42] = (tempval >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tempval = timestamp;
    packetBuffer[43] = (tempval) & 0xFF;

    packetBuffer[44] = 0;
    packetBuffer[45] = 0;
    packetBuffer[46] = 0;
    packetBuffer[47] = 0;

    // Reply to the IP address and port that sent the NTP request

    Udp.beginPacket(Remote, PortNum);
    Udp.write(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
}

void init_wifi() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.hostname(WiFi_hostname);
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  wifiManager.setConnectTimeout(30);       // how long to try to connect for before continuing
  wifiManager.setConfigPortalTimeout(180); // auto close configportal after n seconds
  if (!wifiManager.autoConnect(WiFi_hostname, "password")) {
    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
  }
  //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi

  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  init_wifi();
  //configTime(int timezone, int daylightOffset_sec, const char* server1, const char* server2, const char* server3)
  configTime(10800, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "asia.pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov"); // Ajust for your location GMT(+3 * 3600) = 10800
  now = time(NULL);
  delay(2000);

  server.on ( "/ntp", ntp );
  server.on ( "/ntp_adjust", ntp_adjust );

  ArduinoOTA.begin();
  server.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  // Startup UDP
  Udp.begin(NTP_PORT);
}

void loop() {
  ArduinoOTA.handle();
  server.handleClient();
  processNTP();
}
```

response :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sorry I missed `ESP8266WebServer server(80);` here because my full sketch have many code , everything work like charm with RTS or without.